# How to look at a polynomial ring based on a ring that is not commutative?

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, category-theory

When I first met polynomial rings $R[X]$ I wondered: 'where do they come from?' Later the idea that - if $R$ is commutative - they could be interpreted as $R$-algebras free over a singleton brought relief. But what if $R$ is **not** commutative? Then this interpretation seems to stop functioning. If $R$ is not commutative then free over a singleton also demands elements like (for instance) $X^{n}a$ next to the usual $aX^{n}$, isn't that so? Is there another interpretation for them?

Comment: It seems that your notion of free ring/algebra does not extend to noncommutative rings? Why is that? What definition are you using?

Comment: Yes, besides $aX^2$ for instance, one also has to consider $X^2a$ and $aXbXc$. Which, to name an application, makes most definitions of the quaternionic Mandelbrot set (if they are really quaternionic) wrong or trivial.

Comment: @BillDubuque The ring free over singleton $\{X\}$ is ring $\mathbb Z[X]$. Next to that an $R$-algebra free over $\{X\}$ gives me $R[X]$ but this under condition that $R$ is commutative. So I have interpretations for them. But not yet if $R$ is not-commutative. $R$-algebras are over commutative rings $R$ (as far as I know) aren't they? By $R$-algebra's I am thinking of $R$-modules $A$ equipped with bilinear and associative multiplication on $A$ with a unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great question.  The "free ring over $R$" in one variable in the noncommutative setting is given by $R * \mathbb{Z}[X]$, where the "star" is the free product (= coproduct in the category of rings).  It is universal among all rings $S$ that are equipped with two ring homomorphisms $R \to S$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to S$.

On the other hand, the ring $R[X]$ is isomorphic to $R \otimes \mathbb{Z}[X]$.  It is universal among all rings $S$ that are equipped with homomorphisms $f \colon R \to S$ and $g \colon \mathbb{Z}[X] \to S$, subject to the extra condition that their images centralize one another in $S$ (i.e., if $a = f(r)$ and $b = g(t)$, then $ab = ba$ in $S$).

One way to understand this ring would be to consider its modules/representations.  A right $R[X]$ module $M$ has both a right $R$-action and a $\mathbb{Z}[X]$-action (which we can imagine on either the right or left, as $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is commutative).  The action of the element $X$ on $M$ commutes with the right $R$-action, so $X$ in fact acts by a right $R$-module endomorphism of $M$.  Conversely, if $M$ is any right $R$-module and $\phi$ is any $R$-module endomorphism of $M$, then we have a unique $R[X]$-module structure with the same $R$-action and with $X$ acting via $\phi$.  So to summarize:

> A right $R[X]$-module is a right $R$-module equipped with an $R$-endomorphism.

(Of course, the same sort of statement holds for left $R[X]$-modules.)

I hope this helps you understand the distinction between $R[X]$ and $R * \mathbb{Z}[X]$, as well as the role of $R[X]$.  Let me know if I can clarify anything that I said above.

Comment: Thank you. It will take me some time to get hold of this, but I don't doubt that you will understand that.